# INT 13h: Get next and previous sector?

Tags: assembly

I am writing a small 16bit OS, just for fun, and I am wondering how I can read a disk sector-by-sector.

- Only one sector is read at a time. The data will be stored at memory address X.
- Depending on the user input, either the previous or the next sector will be read to memory address X.

I do understand following graphic:

[image: Diskette graphic]

Also I know the specification of `INT 13h`:

```
AH = 02
AL = number of sectors to read  (1-128 dec.)
CH = track/cylinder number  (0-1023 dec., see below)
CL = sector number  (1-17 dec.)
DH = head number  (0-15 dec.)
DL = drive number (0=A:, 1=2nd floppy, 80h=drive 0, 81h=drive 1)
ES:BX = pointer to buffer
```

But given that I am on a sector X, how can I calculate the required Head/Cylinder/Sector? Also, I don't want to limit the code to a 1.44 MB diskette. The code should also work for other devices.

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_%28BIOS%29

Comment: See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#CHS_conversion).

Comment: Thank you for that hint. LBA is what I am searching for. But I have an additional question; I tried the function l2hts() from MikeOS ( https://github.com/mig-hub/mikeOS/blob/master/source/bootload/bootload.asm ),  and it works fine. But I am not sure if this technique is good if the  bootloader should also run on other media than floppys. Wouldn't it be better to use the Extended LBA method ( http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)#LBA_in_Extended_Mode) ? I tried that too, but it fails for the floppy - so is this method only good for harddisks?

Comment: @DanielMarschall The __int 13h extensions__ were not developed with floppy disk support in mind. So only good for harddisks.